# Java RMI не работает на Android

Tags: java, android, rmi

На пк версии всё работает, в Android приложение крашится на строке

```
Registry registry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry("localhost", 11701);
```

Код в клиенте:

```
try { // подключение к серверу
    Registry registry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry("localhost", 11701);
    service = (IRemoteServer) registry.lookup("remiss");
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

try { // вызов функции
    status = service.tryJoin("login","password");
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    status = "fail";
}
```

Comment: Неудивительно, ведь в Android нет RMI.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev значит в Android нет способов, чтобы использовать Java RMI?

Comment: Да, именно так.

Comment: зачем вы хотите использовать RMI? какую задачу вы решаете?

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что в Android нет RMI

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Стандартный (сановский) Java RMI не работает под Android - это правда.

Но есть реализация RMI - [LipeRMI](http://lipermi.sourceforge.net), которая портируется под Android. Его даже предлагают внести в стандартный Java, чтобы он заменил RMI с протоколом Sun Microsystems как устаревший.

Тестовое приложение для Android, которое использует LipeRMI - [валяется здесь](https://github.com/lilicn/AndroidRMI)